How to get EventViewer value from within .Net8 windows service
I am writing a .NET 8 windows service to track certain details about the logged on user.
If I look at an event from the service in Windows EventViewer there is an item called 'Computer:' that contains something like 'LAP72XXX.XXdomainnameXX.com'.
I want to know if there is a way in my service that I can get the value 'XXdomainnameXX.com'.
PS. it is not Environment.UserDomain

I found what I needed in Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERDNSDOMAIN")

Sadly this only works when I run the service from VS
